# Pyside6 after convert UI to py the widget is empty

Tags: qt-designer, pyside6

İ am learning gui by qt designer, after finish the UI file, i used pyside6 to convert to py file.
Then when u try to test the file, the widget is empty!

Here is the code i try to import the py file.

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from PySide6.QtCore import QFile

from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Ui file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdhzy7a5jw143s1/login_window.ui?dl=0

Py file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ku0atiq2z040ywj/login_window.py?dl=0

Comment: since you haven't included the `ui_mainwindow` i can't really tell whats wrong but i suspect that you have a problem in convertion be sure that  ui_mainwindow is not empty 
`pyside6-uic MainWindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py` be sure that you have used the converting command correctly replace `MainWindow.ui` with your filename .

Comment: Updated with the files

Comment: @SayedHassan No, questions must be self contained, not rely on external website that could make the content no more available (thus making the question invalid and useless to others). Please provide a valid [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as expected the problem was in your main file :

```py
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
```

here you imported the class `Ui_MainWindow` but if we took a look at `ui_mainwindow.py` we found that the name of the class is indeed `Ui_w_loginwindow`

```py
class Ui_w_loginwindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, w_loginwindow):
        if not w_loginwindow.objectName():
            w_loginwindow.setObjectName(u"w_loginwindow")
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

so you have just to import the correct class name which is `Ui_w_loginwindow` and it will run just fine

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from PySide6.QtCore import QFile

from ui_mainwindow import Ui_w_loginwindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_w_loginwindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```